# output variable from a module to another module with for_each in main.tf

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Below is variable file:

```
variable topic_subscription {
  description = "Pub/sub subscription"
  default  = {
    sub1 = {
      name  = "SUB1",
    },
    sub2 = {
      name    = "SUB2"
    }
  }
}
```

main.tf file looping over that variable using for_each:

```
module "subscription_template_sb" {
  source = "./modules/subscription_template_sb"
  for_each     =    var.topic_subscription

  sb           =    each.value.name
}
```

Then in the modules/subscription_template_sb file I have the following:

```
resource "google_pubsub_topic" "sb" {
  name = var.sb
}
```

The module has an output with the following:

```
output "sb_value" {
  value = google_pubsub_topic.sb.id
}
```

I always get:

This object does not have an attribute named "id".

The sb object has a attribute with id. It works if I don't use `for_each` in main.tf

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
value = subscription_template_sb.id
```

it should be

```
value = google_pubsub_topic.sb.id
```

**Updated**

`value = google_pubsub_topic.id` is still wrong. It should be:

```
value = google_pubsub_topic.sb.id
```

Comment: sorry. I updated my question. I was trying with `google_pubsub_topic.sb.id`

Comment: uuugh.. my apologies. I also tried with google_pubsub_topic.sb.id, still same error

Comment: @Krish The answer would fix the thrown error message in the question, and so now there is an either an inaccuracy in the question, or the answer was not integrated as written.

Comment: I updated my question. I've tried with `google_pubsub_topic.sb.id`, but doesn't work if I use `for_each` in main.tf

Comment: @Krish This means that your real code is different then in the question. In that case, no one can help you.